# How can I load XML data into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

On Windows, I can use this statement to load XML data into the database:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 
'c:/users/yourname/desktop/myfile.xml'
 INTO TABLE MyTable
  ROWS IDENTIFED BY '<product>'
```

However, I cannot seem to accomplish this on Ubuntu 11.2.0 with the latest version of MySQL community server installed.

This is the statement I use for my Ubuntu setup:

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL FILE '/home/ryan/tech.xml'
 INTO TABLE `t`
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

So my question is, where do I put the XML files on my web server if I want to access them with MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

You have a mistake on the first line

```
LOAD XML LOCAL FILE '/home/ryan/tech.xml'
```

It is not just `FILE` it is `INFILE`

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/home/ryan/tech.xml'
```

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

All commands or queries are same in windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

You may also have an issue with line breaks - if the xml file was created on Windows, its line breaks will be different to Ubuntu's - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline